# Нестандарный шрифт на сайте

Tags: шрифты

Подключил на сайт нестандарный шрифт, но работает он только в случае, если шрифт установлен у меня в Windows, можно ли как-то обойти это, чтобы не прибегать к картинке и пользователи могли без проблем видеть данный шрифт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему сам. Воспользовался онлайн-генератором шрифтов, для генерации их в разных форматах, чтобы все было кроссбраузерно. В итоге код получился примерно такой:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CenturyGothic';
    src: url('fonts/CenturyGothic/CenturyGothic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/CenturyGothic/CenturyGothic.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('fonts/CenturyGothic/CenturyGothic.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/CenturyGothic/CenturyGothic.svg#CenturyGothic') format('svg');
}
```

Если кому-то интересно, то вот сервисы, которыми я пользовался:

```
1) http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
2) http://www.web-font-generator.com/
```

Нужно было сгенерировать форматы для двух разных шрифтов, на одном из сервисов он не хотел заливаться, пришлось воспользоваться другим.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно подключить шрифт в CSS вот так:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myCoolFont'; /* по этому имени мы будем обращаться к шрифтц*/
    src: url('http://domain.com/fonts/font.ttf'); /* URL по которому лежит шрифт */
}
```

Теперь в определении стилей можно использовать ваш шрифт:

```
font-family: myCoolFont;
```

http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-face

Comment: Спасибо, я так и сделал, но работает он только при условии, что у меня в системе есть этот шрифт